# QML change path in PathView with NumberAnimation of its items

Tags: qt, animation, path, qml

I have a PathView with Rectangle as the delegate. I change the PathView.path to another path and I want to play animation of moving PathView items to their new positions. Something like this:

```
PathView {
  id: pathView
  delegate: Rectangle {
    Behavior on x {
      NumberAnimation {
        duration: 5000
      }
    }
  }

  path: path1
}
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to do somehow?

Comment: Explain yourself better.

Comment: @eyllanesc Well, I have a ListModel and I want to place the model items along a path, then I want to change the path, so positions of items will be changed, and I wan't to make that change smooth.

Comment: I think I'm understanding, it would be advisable that this comment is in your question, it would also be useful to show a diagram, image, etc, that describes what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, changing the "PathView.path" to another "Path" will destroy and recreate delegates just like changing a model.

A workaround can be done with "states". You create multiple blank PathLine and set its x and y values from states. You give the animation from "transitions"

This Sample code will initially have 3 data items in the model. In between the animation, it reloads the model with 5 data and still works in a continuous fashion without any glitch to the animation.

```
PathView {

    id: pathView
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 100

    model: 3


    path: Path {
        id: pathLines
        PathLine { id: pl1 }
        PathLine { id: pl2 }
        PathLine { id: pl3 }
        PathLine { id: pl4 }
        PathLine { id: pl5 }
    }

    state: 'zigzag'

    states: [
        State {
            name: "zigzag"
            PropertyChanges { target: pathLines; startX: 0; startY: 100; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl1; x: 200; y: 300; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl2; x: 500; y: 100; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl3; x: 600; y: 300; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl4; x: 800; y: 100; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl5; x: 1000; y: 300; }
        },
        State {
            name: "close"
            PropertyChanges { target: pathLines; startX: pathView.width/2; startY: pathView.height/2; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl1; x: pathView.width/2; y: pathView.height/2; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl2; x: pathView.width/2; y: pathView.height/2; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl3; x: pathView.width/2; y: pathView.height/2; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl4; x: pathView.width/2; y: pathView.height/2; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl5; x: (pathView.width/2) + 1; y: pathView.height/2; } // Note: "+1" to fix disappearance bug
        },
        State {
            name: "open"
            PropertyChanges { target: pathLines; startX: pathView.width/2; startY: pathView.height/4; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl1; x: pathView.width/2; y: pathView.height/4; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl2; x: pathView.width/2; y: pathView.height/4; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl3; x: pathView.width/2; y: pathView.height/4; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl4; x: pathView.width/2; y: pathView.height/4; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl5; x: pathView.width/2 + 1; y: pathView.height/4; } // Note: "+1" to fix disappearance bug
        },
        State {
            name: "triangle"
            PropertyChanges { target: pathLines; startX: 200; startY: 500; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl1; x: 400; y: 700; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl2; x: 600; y: 500; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl3; x: 350; y: 500; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl4; x: 300; y: 500; }
            PropertyChanges { target: pl5; x: 250; y: 500; }
        }

    ]

    transitions: [
       Transition {
            to: 'zigzag'
            SmoothedAnimation { properties: "x,y,startX,startY"; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad; duration: 2000; onFinished: pathView.state = 'triangle'  }
        },
        Transition {
            to: 'triangle'
            SmoothedAnimation { properties: "x,y,startX,startY"; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad; duration: 2000; }
        },
        Transition {
            to: 'close'
            SmoothedAnimation { properties: "x,y,startX,startY"; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad; duration: 2000; }
            onRunningChanged: {
                if (!running) {
                    pathView.model = 5
                    pathView.state = 'open'
                }
            }
        },
        Transition {
            from: "close"
            to: 'open'
            SmoothedAnimation { properties: "x,y,startX,startY"; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad; duration: 2000; }
            onRunningChanged: !running ? pathView.state = 'triangle' : ''
        }
    ]

    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 20
        height: 20
        radius: 20
        color: 'green'
    }
}

Controls.Button {
     anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
     anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
     text: 'Start Animation'
     onClicked: pathView.state = 'close'
}
```

The state names like "zigzag" and "triangle" does not resemble its real shape, just some random shape for test purposes.